joblib.externals.loky.process_executor.ShutdownExecutorError: cannot schedule new futures after shutdown in Parallel method
Getting such error using Joblib library in Python 3.11:

Exception has occurred: ShutdownExecutorError cannot schedule new
futures after shutdown   File
"D:*\app\tools\keywords\TagSpellChecker.py",
line 52, in ortho_check
corrected_words = (Parallel(n_jobs=cpus_number)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "D:*\app\tools\keywords\TagSpellChecker.py",
line 18, in call
orthography = self.ortho_check(self.keywords)   File "D:*\app\tools\get_data\get_meta_tags.py",
line 19, in get_meta_tags
passed_keywords: str = TagSpellChecker(keywords, limit)()   File "D:*\app\tools\tagging_media\tagging_requests\image_tagging_request.py",
line 38, in image_tagging_request
data: Dict = get_meta_tags(content=content, limit=limit) joblib.externals.loky.process_executor.ShutdownExecutorError: cannot
schedule new futures after shutdown

Code is in each error occurs:
    def ortho_check(self, words: list | str) -> list:
    if isinstance(words, str):
        words = words.split('; ')

    empty_words_removed: list = list(filter(lambda el: el != '', words))
    misspelled: Dict[int, str] = self.unknown(empty_words_removed)
    misspelled_length: int = len(misspelled)

    if misspelled_length == 0:
        return empty_words_removed
    elif misspelled_length == 1:
        corrected_words = self._process_word(words=misspelled, index=0)

        j = 0
        for index, word in misspelled.items():
            empty_words_removed[index] = corrected_words[j]
            j += 1
    elif misspelled_length > 1:
        cpus_number: int = min(multiprocessing.cpu_count()/2, misspelled_length)
        corrected_words = (Parallel(n_jobs=cpus_number) #<-- error coming from here
                   (delayed(self._process_word)
                    (words=misspelled, index=i) for i in range(0, misspelled_length)))

        j = 0
        for index, word in misspelled.items():
            empty_words_removed[index] = corrected_words[j]
            j += 1

    ortho_checked = empty_words_removed
    return ortho_checked

Error occurs in random time. The last time it occurs variables was:
cpus_number = 7; 
misspelled = {18: 'stonecutting', 32: 'gemstoneart', 50: 'raditional', 56: 'opticalillusion', 57: 'semi-precious', 68: 'jewelrydesign', 74: 'richcolors'}; 
misspelled_length = 7;

How to sovle such problem?
